# Python has encountered a unicode problem with a file location

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently just messing around getting the hang of discord programming so I can make an actual game but I encountered a problem, when I try and make python find a file I get a Unicode error I don't understand.
This is the code: (The error is attached as an image):

```
import discord

import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

from PIL import Image

bot = discord.Client()

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        
        if message.content == "Big red button":
            await message.channel.send("Oh no i died")
            quit()
        elif message.content == "Cinnamon roll":
            await message.channel.send("Here you go")
            await channel.send(file=discord.File('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Cinnamon_Roll.png'))
            
client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Please *do not post images of error messages*. You should post it as formatted text in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your error image, But you have invalid escape sequences in your path.
Replace line 26 with this:

```
await channel.send(file=discord.File('C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\Python\Cinnamon_Roll.png'))
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered a lot quicker than I was expecting

Comment: Glad i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a class if it is this simple. Keep in mind that anyone can stop the bot like this you can make an extra check

```py
if message.content == "Big red button" and message.author.id == 'OWNER_ID_HERE':
```

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # don't respond to ourselves
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content == "Big red button":
        await message.channel.send("Oh no i died")
        await bot.logout()
    elif message.content == "Cinnamon roll":
        await message.channel.send("Here you go")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Cinnamon_Roll.png'))
        
bot.run('TOKEN_HERE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of escaping the slashes with another slash, you can also do this...

```
await channel.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Cinnamon_Roll.png'))
```

Keeping the  `r` symbol makes it raw.

The reason python doesn't accept that `\` is because the slash is special and is used for unicode characters